# Merge specifications of different types in Criteria Query Specifications

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm having an `Activity` entity which is in `@ManyToOne` relationship with `Event` entity and their corresponding metamodels - `Activity_` and `Event_` were generated by JPA model generator.

I've created specialized classes `ActivitySpecifications` and `EventSpecifications`. Those classes contain only static methods whose return `Specification`. For example:

```
public interface EventSpecifications {

   static Specification<Event> newerThan(LocalDateTime date) {
       return (root, cq, cb) -> cb.gt(Event_.date, date);
   }

  ...
}
```

so when I want to build query matching multiple specifications, I can execute following statement using `findAll` on `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event>` repository.

```
EventSpecifications.newerThan(date).and(EventSpecifications.somethingElse())
```

and `ActivitySpecifications` example:

```
static Specification<Activity> forActivityStatus(int status) { ... }
```

How do I use `EventSpecifications` from `ActivitySpecifications` ? I mean like merge specifications of different type. I'm sorry, but I don't even know how to ask it properly, but theres simple example:

I want to select all activities with status = `:status` and where `activity.event.date` is greater than `:date`

```
static Specification<Activity> forStatusAndNewerThan(int status, LocalDateTime date) {
    return forActivityStatus(status)
         .and((root, cq, cb) -> root.get(Activity_.event) .... 
         // use EventSpecifications.newerThan(date) somehow up there
}
```

Is something like this possible?

The closest thing that comes to my mind is using the following:

```
return forActivityStatus(status)
             .and((root, cq, cb) -> cb.isTrue(EventSpecifications.newerThan(date).toPredicate(???, cq, cb));
```

where `???` requires `Root<Event>`, but I can only get `Path<Event>` using `root.get(Activity_.event)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its basic form, specifications are designed to be composable only if they refer to the same root.

However, it shouldn't be too difficult to introduce your own interface which is easily convertible to `Specification` and which allows for specifications refering to arbitrary entities to be composed.

First, you add the following interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface PathSpecification<T> {

    default Specification<T> atRoot() {
        return this::toPredicate;
    }

    default <S> Specification<S> atPath(final SetAttribute<S, T> pathAttribute) {
        // you'll need a couple more methods like this one for all flavors of attribute types in order to make it fully workable
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            return toPredicate(root.join(pathAttribute), query, cb);
        };
    }

    @Nullable
    Predicate toPredicate(Path<T> path, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder);
}
```

You then rewrite the specifications as follows:

```
public class ActivitySpecifications {

    public static PathSpecification<Activity> forActivityStatus(ActivityStatus status) {
        return (path, query, cb) -> cb.equal(path.get(Activity_.status), cb.literal(status));
    }
}

public class EventSpecifications {

    public static PathSpecification<Event> newerThan(LocalDateTime date) {
        return (path, cq, cb) -> cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(path.get(Event_.createdDate), date);
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to compose specifications in the following manner:

```
activityRepository.findAll(
    forActivityStatus(ActivityStatus.IN_PROGRESS).atRoot()
    .and(newerThan(LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.AUGUST, 1, 0, 0)).atPath(Activity_.events))
)
```

The above solution has the additional advantage in that specifying `WHERE` criteria is decoupled from specifying paths, so if you have multiple associations between `Activity` and `Event`, you can reuse `Event` specifications for all of them.

Comment: Thank you, I've actually solved it using very similar way.

Comment: How does `forActivityStatus` return `PathSpecification` instead of `Specification`?

Comment: So that you could call `atPath` on it, if needed. But, if you need just a regular specification, there's also the conversion method, `atRoot`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the why. As to how, well, it simply does. `PathSpecification`  is a `@FunctionalInterface`, so...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following :

```
ClassA {
 id;
}

ClassB {
 foreignId; //id of A
}
```

For combining `Specification<ClassA> specA, Specification<ClassB> specB`

```
specB = specB.and(combineSpecs(specA);

private static Specification<ClassB> combineSpecs(Specification<ClassA> specA) {
   return (root_b,query,builder) {
     Subquery<ClassA> sub = query.subquery(ClassA.class);
     Root<ClassA> root_a = sub.from(ClassA.class);
     Predicate p1 = specA.toPredicate(root_a,query,builder);
     Predicate p2 = builder.equal(root_a.get("id"),root_b.get("foreignId"));
     Predicate predicate = builder.and(p1,p2);
     sub.select(root_a).where(predicate);
     return builder.exists(sub);
   };
}
```